# Rename list files cannot find files

Tags: python, operating-system

I'm trying to rename files by replacing out commas.
I have a function that finds the errors and passes
to another function on a button click.
The second example is obvious, however I believe
os.rename in the first example is taken this back again.
What am I doing wrong?

```
            if self.filenames:
                    print self.dirname  ## finds directory
                    path = self.dirname
                    dirList=os.listdir(path)                        
                    for self.filename in dirList:
                            print self.dirname ## finds directory
                            f = self.filename
                            print f ## finds c,1.txt !!!
                            if not f.startswith('.') and f.find(',') >= 0:
                                    os.rename(f, f.replace(',',''))
```

Traceback:
c,1.txt
The system cannot find the file specified

```
            if self.filenames:
                    print self.dirname ## finds directory                        
                    for self.filename in os.listdir("."):
                            print self.dirname ## finds directory
                            f = self.filename
                            print f
                            if not f.startswith('.') and f.find(',') >= 0:
                                    os.rename(f, f.replace(',',''))
```

Replaces files in the working directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change `os.rename(f, f.replace(',',''))` to `os.rename(os.path.join(self.dirname, f), os.path.join(self.dirname, f.replace(',','')))`. Essentially the `rename` function expects a valid path to a file, and you need to concatenate the base directory path to the filename if the file is not in the current directory.

Comment: That did it Subhasis.  I'll remember to include os.path.join